# Android ctor for static object not called

Tags: java, android, qt, qml, qtquick2

Writing an android app using primarily Qt and QML, I'm trying to follow the [example for sending notifications](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html). When I run the example things work as expected but when I put nearly identical code into my app it doesn't call the ctor for one of the static objects so things fail. Here is my Java code:

```
package com.me.myApp;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationClient extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "myApp::NotificationClient";
    private static NotificationManager m_notificationManager;
    private static Notification.Builder m_builder;
    private static NotificationClient m_instance;

    public NotificationClient() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Doing ctor");
        m_instance = this;
    }

    public static void notify(String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Doing the update thing");
        if(m_instance == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "I have a null instance");
        }
        try {
            if (m_notificationManager == null) {
                m_notificationManager = (NotificationManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                m_builder = new Notification.Builder(m_instance);
//              m_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                m_builder.setContentTitle("A message from Qt!");
            }

            m_builder.setContentText(s);
            m_notificationManager.notify(1, m_builder.build());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Notify error: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the log files, it's getting into the `notify()` function but `m_instance` is `null` because the `NotificationClient` ctor is never called.

What would cause this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An android Qt application is compound of a thin Java layer which, at start-up, calls the Qt application packaged as a dynamic `so` library. More details can be found in the [first](https://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-1/) blog post of a nice series held by Mr Vatra @ KDAB.

The Java layer, which happens to be the main activity plus some utility classes, is available in the [Qt code base](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/android/java/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings).

When a new Android project is created Qt Creator automatically generate a `manifest` file that uses the default classes available in Qt. As long as you use the default setup everything works fine.

In your case you had to extend the default main activity to add your custom
Java code, resulting in a new name for the main activity (`NotificationClient`). However the manifest points to the (still) available base class i.e. you have in your manifest:

```
android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity"
```

In this scenario the superclass ctor is called and thus the `static` variable is not assigned with a valid value, resulting in the `nullPointerException` issue. Setting  the correct new main activity in the manifest solves the issue:

```
android:name="com.me.myApp.NotificationClient"
```

I advice you in carefully reading the blog posts series linked above since they make easy to understand the Java <--> C++ interactions in an Android Qt project.

Answer (score 0):

`m_instance` (which doesn't follow the Java naming conventions) is initialized only in the `NotificationClient` constructor, but it is a `static` member. Besides that this means that every instance initialization will alter that value unpredictably, the constructor is never actually called in your code. A static member of a type does *not* get its constructor called magically; it only gets constructed when the code calls for it to be.

You should never assume that something happens a certain way, you should know what happens by dint of study of the documentation.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Without an explicit initialization, member values hold their default values; in the case of your `NotificationClient` member, that value is `null`.

Comment: My code is taken almost verbatim from the qt example. Looking through their example again I don't see any explicit initialization of a java NotificationClient object. Based on your description, the example is not written correctly and it's just an accident that it works?